# Which benefits personal anti-spams bring w.r.t. e-mail provider's ones?

Tags: email, spam

Assuming that an e-mail service provider is using an excellent anti-spam software, for what reason its users should employ a personal anti-spam?

Answer (score 1):

The only reason that I can think is to improve the detection on the service provider. For example a message that is not label as spam from the provider(the detection is not correct or the MTA don't have the signature or rule to detect that sample) and the user label as spam and report the issue so the provider can add new rules/signature for detect the issue. This mechanism is easy on this example but can be complicated depending on the environment, you can think for example on if the provider receives 10 messages from different users that label as spam then generate the rules/signatures, but basically is the same concept.